# Android back button not working after onKeyUp() is overridden

Tags: android, android-navigation

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Once the above method is added to an activity, the back button stops working but the other two buttons on the navigation bar - home and overview - still work perfectly.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because You're always returning `false` from it. It should actually be conditional & in other cases, you should call `super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);`

**Example:**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (condition == true){
            //do something
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode,event);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know why the home and overview buttons still worked flawlessly while the back key did not?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. The back button sudden stopped working while I only handle the Volume buttons. @Hong The Home and Apps buttons are system keys, similar to the power key, and you are not allowed to "swallow" it up.